# Read csv file give weird result with encoding UTF8

Tags: node.js, csv, encoding, utf-8

So i have a problem while doing my project,i'm trying to read my csv file,i have try using encoding utf16 and utf8,and both give me weird result.

Below is the result from utf8

```
:�4^xr7zd5fixekg_2020-01-31T190000_88ffa7d6bd0e31b86d9c3ac3d7c601f5_c3575d.csv�[o�8���ST}��6Ɨ��U��msQ��j4!c�ԛ" U���k$�;���l�����ǿ��vp���;�a0.�Ggݳ���u�"�
��G��?
      �No��u^���%8>>v��ο9_�L��7燘�C���
��韊��m���9��Yn��Z���",2!':��T�dJ1�
                                    3N�d�Ea����l�鼼u�\�͙<L��H��F��ֲ(O�
                                                                      �Urj�$,Lu��ަ����:<ME�&u�B��DQuO'c1�3���<�v��өV�(�M�L�:��tl��悍�T_����~k%�.�5�D�����n^�J/���L$�X�b�=�T����id(S�W�%����>u#���m�y㯴-�s��z�M�2]�쩉uU��   ��|j��J��UC���Օ2=O��$����/�۰H':i.�p���k�Q����i����}81IIB/K!��S����<��������-�q�:�6ы������V:�_g�t����s��"��nN�MY��H9���sL?;�{:
                                                                             ��epΕV3�O
                                                                                        ����R[�g���I�����'}�/]B��b��y��P��G
                                                                                                                                ƜqB!#��TzHcJ�XBI�����b�b�A]��3�1��y]y8��'�� ��(�S;iw����f�B�3��9�y�!�c�J��G.�(v#D��
x��9����a�:�w�`|�&o]��#�hL%+ybc`y���B��f��3hK�'1�9G0��d
o�s����5�=�'����x��U�^_t��_�˳A�^�]u:�wH����Q;��G�����'��m�&-����U�ӗp0�c�{H��
                    ������l�;�^�~��j��!��t��!"���e�=�����eݼ�)k�r���Y�=��!;�~/Y�}�!�
                                                                                      ��6Ѷ�"��1��Y�}�C�֖�����-���ԮB^U|�I�ۈ�㹑����;E������6�,7��K�7�(�䒺�Ş���,\y,c)-��<�"��ǩ�e#@Ƒ��`o
                                                    ���3�q�[�ĝ(N����˿��t�K�|���t���"C��ë����f;�J�=Z�o_��i�����g��;��y4o_;�����U��%��!�� �`������dZ>!;��ԉw�/,
```

and Below is my code

```
function readFile(req, res, next) {
  const csvString = fs.readFileSync('./server/components/engagement/downloaded.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' })
  console.log(csvString.toString())
};
```

I can open the file with excel,but if i try to open it in visual studio code it says **The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding**

UPDATE

So i try to use package neat-csv https://flaviocopes.com/node-read-csv/ , it gives me weird string again,but i think i get closer to my goals this time(maybe ?). Below is the output from the package.

```
[ { '\u001f�\b\b:�4^\u0000\u0003xr7zd5fixekg_2020-01-31T190000_88ffa7d6bd0e31b86d9c3ac3d7c601f5_c3575d.csv\u0000�[o�8\u0014���ST}��6Ɨ��U��msQ��j4\u001a!c�ԛ\u0004" \u0019U���k\u0002$�;���l��\u0001���ǿ��vp���;�a0�\b.�Ggݳ���u�"�': '��G��?\f�No��u^\u0006���%8>>v��ο9_�L��7燘�C���' },
  { '\u001f�\b\b:�4^\u0000\u0003xr7zd5fixekg_2020-01-31T190000_88ffa7d6bd0e31b86d9c3ac3d7c601f5_c3575d.csv\u0000�[o�8\u0014���ST}��6Ɨ��U��msQ��j4\u001a!c�ԛ\u0004" \u0019U���k\u0002$�;���l��\u0001���ǿ��vp���;�a0�\b.�Ggݳ���u�"�':
     '��韊�\u0012�m���9��Yn��Z���",2!\':��T�dJ1�\u000b3N�\u0006d�Ea����l�鼼u\u0018�\\�͙<L��H��F��ֲ(O�\u000b�U\u0000rj�$,Lu��\u0011ަ���\u001d�:\u000f<ME�&u�B��DQuO\'c1�3�\u0014��\u000f<�v��\u0010өV�(\u001e�M�L�:��t\u001dl��悍�T_����~k%�.�5�D\u0017�����n^�J/���L$�X�b�=�T���\u001e�i\u0019d(S�W�%����>u#���m�y㯴-\u0019�s��z�\u0019M�2]�쩉uU��\t��|j��J��UC���Օ2=O��$����/�۰H\':i\u001a.�p���k�Q����i����}81IIB/K!��S����<\u000f��������\u001e-�q�:�6ы������V\u000e:�_g�\u0001\u000et�\u000f�\u0019��s��"�\u0000�nN\u0019�M\u0011Y��H9���sL?;�{:\u000b��\u0010epΕV3�O\u000b�\u0007\u000f�\u0015��R[\u0003\u0002\u001b�g���I�����\'}\u0000�/]B��b�\u0011�y��P��G\fƜq\u0007B!\u0014#��TzHcJ\u0004�X�\bBI�����b�b�A]��\u00063�1��y]y8��\'�\u0001\u0002�\t��(�S;\u0010iw����f�B\u000e�3��\u001d\u00079�\u001dy�!�c��\bJ��G.�(v#D�\u0007\u0011�' },
  { '\u001f�\b\b:�4^\u0000\u0003xr7zd5fixekg_2020-01-31T190000_88ffa7d6bd0e31b86d9c3ac3d7c601f5_c3575d.csv\u0000�[o�8\u0014���ST}��6Ɨ��U��msQ��j4\u001a!c�ԛ\u0004" \u0019U���k\u0002$�;���l��\u0001���ǿ��vp���;�a0�\b.�Ggݳ���u�"�':
     '\u0000�\u0011�\bS\u0000\u0003�$�\\!�X�V\'A�\u001f�J�m�\u001f&x����;\u0010�\u0006~5\\8���n?<�\u0019�\u0006�w(\u0001��;\t<�HPR�d\rx��9����a\u001b�:�\u0006w�\u001c`\u001b\u0003|\to]��#�hL%+yb\u0017c`y���B��\u0000f��3hK�\'1�9�\bG0�' },
  { '\u001f�\b\b:�4^\u0000\u0003xr7zd5fixekg_2020-01-31T190000_88ffa7d6bd0e31b86d9c3ac3d7c601f5_c3575d.csv\u0000�[o�8\u0014���ST}��6Ɨ��U��msQ��j4\u001a!c�ԛ\u0004" \u0019U���k\u0002$�;���l��\u0001���ǿ��vp���;�a0�\b.�Ggݳ���u�"�':
     '2�bfg+�W�����U�-�E�5�U�^_t��_�˳A�\u0013^�]u:�wH���\u0013�Q;��G�����\'��m�&-����U�ӗp0\u001a�c�{H�\u0003�\ro�s���\u0003�5�=�\'����\u0011x�\u000b����\u000e�\u001b�l\u000f�\u0019;�^�~��j��!�\u001b7�t��!"���e�=�����eݼ\u0017�)k�r���Y�=��!;�~/Y�}�!�\u000b�\u0003�6Ѷ�"\u0010��1��Y�}�C\u0010�\u0007֖�����-\u0017���Ԯ\u0003\u0010B^U\u0004|�I�ۈ�㹑��\u0002��;E������6�\u0010,7��K�7\u001b�(�\u001e䒺�Ş���,`\b\\\u0004y,c\u001d)-��<\u0002�"\u0011��ǩ�e\u000f#@\u0000Ƒ��`o\u0005\f\u0018�\u0018\u0012�\u001e�3�q�[�ĝ(N��\u0014��˿\u0016��t�K\u001d\u001e�|���t���"C��ë����f;�J�=Z�o_\u0012��i�\u001f����g��;�\u001f�y4\u0017o_\u0018;\u0007�\u0012���\u001b�\u001fU\u0010��%��\u0005!�� �`����\u0001��d\u0002Z>!;\u001c��\u0005ԉw�/,\u0000\u0000' } ]
```

Comment: The file is perhaps an xlsx file with the csv extension. A valid CSV is readable by any editor, just to make sure, open your "csv" with Excel and then save it as CSV

Comment: Yes i think it is xlsx file,but i don't think save as CSV will solve my problem,because i want to save the file temporarily and copy the data and then delete it,all with code.

Comment: Then you must use a package for reading the file, try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#reading-xlsx`

Comment: Hey i have tried the package,but the result give me an object that have rows and columns key,but what i don't understand is,there is `[Circular]` inside the rows and columns key,and i think `[Circular]` is my data,so how do i access it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your file looks like an `xlsx`, you should read the file using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs` package.

Check out the demo below:

```js
const Excel = require('exceljs');
// read from a file
var filename = '/absolute/or/relative/path/to/file.xlsx';
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
  .then(function() {
    // use workbook

    workbook.eachSheet(function(worksheet, sheetId) {

      worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
        console.log('Row ' + rowNumber + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(row.values));

        // Iterate over all cells in a row (including empty cells)
        row.eachCell({
          includeEmpty: true
        }, function(cell, colNumber) {
          console.log('Cell ' + colNumber + ' = ' + cell.value);

          // update the current cell value
          worksheet.getCell(cell.fullAddress).value = cell.value + ' ' + cell.value;

        });

      });

    });

    // target a specific cell
    worksheet.getCell('A1').value = 'new value';

    // after everything is done you can write the data to another file
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('/path/to/my_new_file.xlsx')
      .then(function() {
        // done
      });

  });
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the filename parameter,i try to give only the filename ,it gives me an error and i already try to give absolute path but it still give me error,the error is `Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ?` .But if i try `workbook.csv.readFile(filename)` it gives me array of weird string like the example from my first question.

Comment: There is a chance your file is actually an `xls`, as far as i'm aware exceljs supports only `xlsx and csv`, in that case find another package that will read `xls`. I hope your file is not password-protected.